# Reading from and writing to file in The Qt Resource System (qt 5.0.2)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have the code below. I am using Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2012_64bit-Release. I am not able to read the file. I get the debug error message of "Cannot open file for reading".There is some problem for me with resource files. Any idea how I can fix it? Thanks!

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QResource>
#include <QIODevice>


void Read(QString Filename){
    QFile mFile(Filename);

    if(!mFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)){
        qDebug() << "could not open file for read";
        return;
    }

        QTextStream in(&mFile);
        QString mText = in.readAll();

        qDebug() << mText;

        mFile.close();



}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Read(":/MyFiles/myfile.txt");
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: 1) Add mFile.errorString() to your debug output to learn more about the exact reason 2) Add the contents of the qrc file

Comment: Note that Qt resources can be read but not written once compiled.

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem. The Error string was "Unknown error".
  Solution was to add `INCLUDEPATH += .` from @gatto's answer and run commands from menu:

```
1. Build -> Clean all
2. Build -> Run qmake
3. Build -> Rebuild All
```

Answer (score 2):

`test.pro`:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = test
INCLUDEPATH += .

# Input
SOURCES += main.cpp
RESOURCES += test.qrc
```

`test.qrc`:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
 <qresource>
    <file>MyFiles/myfile.txt</file>
 </qresource>
 </RCC>
```

`main.cpp` is from your question. Works fine.

That said, if you still have the problem, you should post minimal Qt project (including .pro and .qrc files), that has the error.