# Load svg from Qt resource to string and change color

Tags: qt, svg, pyqt

I try to change the color of an button icon at runtime. If I have the svg as xml its easy to do. Is it possible to load the xml text representation from an resource file?

Solved: Yes it's possible:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sip
try:
    sip.setapi('QString', 2)
    sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)
except ValueError, e:
    log.error(e)

from  PyQt4.QtGui import *
from  PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtSvg import *
import sys
import resources_rc

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    f = QFile(":/icons/icons/svg/draw-freehand.svg")
    if f.open(QFile.ReadOnly | QFile.Text):
        textStream = QTextStream(f)
        svgData = textStream.readAll()
        f.close()

    svg = QSvgRenderer(QByteArray(svgData))
    qim = QImage(32, 32, QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    qim.fill(0)
    painter = QPainter()

    painter.begin(qim)
    svg.render(painter)
    painter.end()

    qim.save('test2.png')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the SVG source code from QRC into a QString and do string manipulation from there:

[Reading from and writing to file in The Qt Resource System (qt 5.0.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250593/reading-from-and-writing-to-file-in-the-qt-resource-system-qt-5-0-2)